# selenium ide: how to verify value from external css file

Tags: selenium-ide

myi would like to know if it is possible to check values from an external CSS file with Selenium IDE?

my html:

```
<div id="myBlock">
```

my css style:

```
#myBlock {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

i need to verify the background-color. I tryed to use verifyAttribute with //*[@id="myBlock"]@background or //*[@id="myBlock"]@style, but the attribute is not found. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A combination of storeEval and JavaScript's getComputedStyle has worked successfully in the past. Of course, you'll have to enable JavaScript in the browser!

The below, when run in Selenium IDE against your HTML, should return the RGB code of the HEX code.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementsByClassName('myBlock')[0]).getPropertyValue('background-color')</td>
    <td>StoredColorVariable</td>
</tr>
```

The variable `StoredColorVariable` will now contain the background color rgb(255, 255, 255).

Comment: Not working for me, got the following log: "[error] Threw an exception: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle is not an object." And why "ByClass" if i got an id name in my div?

Comment: @nitche What happens if you replace the middle line with this? `<td>window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementById('myBlock')).getPropertyValue('color')</td>` By the way, the above works off the attribute, not the tag type which is why I'm using 'getElementById'. Also the case matters...